# Bigquery String to date invalid, safe.parse returns null #standardSQL

Tags: datetime, parsing, google-bigquery, casting

I am trying to convert a date value ingested from SFMC as a string. Attempts and results below:

1. PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',  '6/22/2017’)        returns “invalid date”
   2.safe.PARSE_DATE('%m-%d-%Y',Timesent)         returns null results

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if it was because the day of month had no leading zero, because according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date), %d means the day of the month as a decimal number (01-31).

But your first example worked OK for me in a BigQuery SQL workspace anyway as per below. Your second example has hyphens rather than slashes in the format mask, and BigQuery returns a mismatch error for me.

Are you certain about the date value which is failing for you?

[image]